# Where is my mistake calculating $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin(x)}{x^2+4}~dx$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Where is my mistake calculating $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin(x)}{x^2+4}~\text{d}x$$

Let $$f(z)=\frac{z\sin(z)}{z^2+4}$$ it has simple poles at $\pm 2i$. We take the standard half circle path with $\text{Im} (z)>0$ and then by Residue theorem (the residue at $2i$ is $(i/2)\sinh(2)$) we have $$\int_{\text{Path}}f(z)~dz=2\pi i \cdot (i/2)\sinh(2)=-\pi\sinh(2)$$

Then it is just the routine parametrization of the straight line segment of the path and showing that the integral along the arc goes to $0$ as $R \to \infty$ using the $ML$ lemma and so we get

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin(x)}{x^2+4}~\text{d}x=-\pi\sinh(2)$$ however this is not right according to Wolfram it should be $\pi/e^2$.

Can anyone spot where I have made a mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesn't it look strange to you that an integral expected to be positive (the main contribute comes from a neighbourhood of the origin) turns out to be negative? The issue is that such function does not fulfill Jordan's lemma (the contribute given by the integral on the semicircle arc does not vanish as the radius of such arc goes to infinity). The escape route is the following:
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{x\sin(x)}{x^2+4}\,dx = \text{Im}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{x e^{ix}}{x^2+4}\,dx =\text{Im}\left[2\pi i\cdot\text{Res}\left(\frac{z e^{iz}}{z^2+4},z=2i\right)\right]\tag{1}$$
and it gives the expected result $\color{red}{\large\frac{\pi}{e^2}}$.